# New create react app project have 12969 vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, security, npm, create-react-app

I am setting up a new project with create react app. But in the first place when the create react app tool finish i got 12969 severity vulnerabilities.

"create-react-app project-name"

Is a blank project with create react app no other dependencies installed.

- I already try:

  - "npm audit fix" dont solve anything
  - Downgrade nodejs from 12.6.0 to stable 10.16.0
  - Restart pc (i had to try)
  - Install create-ract-app globally
  - "npm clean cache --force"
  - Delete "package-lock.json" and "node_modules" folder, then "npm cache verify" and "npm install"

[12969 vulnerabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNUmO.png)

Comment: They know https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7364

Comment: Oh ok, i was searching for info a lot of time but this post is 37min ago, thanks for share.